# PyMC3 model does not generate sample data close to the observed data

Tags: python, mcmc, pymc3

I have created an MCMC model using PyMC3 following the steps provided in the following example:

https://pymc-devs.github.io/pymc3/notebooks/LKJ.html

The results, I get is similar to the following image:
[image]

The simulated samples are following nicely the same pattern that observed data have. However, the range in X and Y is much smaller. Does anyone know how I can have samples that cover a range of numbers similar to the observed data?

Answer (score 0):

If your posterior predictive samples are that different from your observations, than clearly *something* is wrong. But without more information it is impossible to tell what. A couple of ideas:

- The sampler has trouble (look at traceplots and check for divergences)
- Your model doesn't fit the dataset (improve the model)
- Your posterior predictive samples are somehow wrong or not comparable to your actual samples. How did you generate them?